# How to show a math. vector inside a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

at the moment I ‘am working on a little program that shows the vertices of a 3D-modell as a table (datagrid). I’ve written a class “vertex” witch contains the coordinates, color etc. as 1x3 float-arrays. When I bind the list of Vertices to the datagrid it looks as follows (pictures not embbeded because I didn't got the needed reputation):

[Current view of the window](http://abload.de/image.php?img=vertexe2x1jvp.jpg)

It should look like this:

[Like it should look (made in Word)](http://abload.de/image.php?img=vertexe3pdjhd.jpg)

As you can see in the last column, I’ve already tried to embed the array as an additional datagrid inside the first one, this failed probably because the datagrid didn’t has a column template for datagrids. 
After that I tried to create a template like in this MSDN-article: http:// msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950(v=vs.95).aspx

The created inner datagrids got the right dimensions but stay empty, probably a binding mistake.

Sourcecode:
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Mod2_Leser.Tabellenanzeige"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Tabellenanzeige" Height="480" Width="640" Background="AliceBlue">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DGCellTemplate">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Koordinaten}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DGCellEditingTemplate">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Koordinaten, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid x:Name="Grid2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--<RowDefinition Height="35"/>-->
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="80" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <DataGrid x:Name="DG" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True"
                      Margin="10,10,10,0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGeneratingColumn="DG_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>
            <Button x:Name="BClose" Content="Schließen" Grid.Row="1" Height="30" Margin="10,10,10,10" Click="BClose_Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
public Tabellenanzeige(KonBereich KB, bool? vertinsttria) {
        InitializeComponent();
        KB.UpdateDGs();
        if (vertinsttria == true) {
            #region Vertexe
            Title = "Vertex-Ansicht";
            Binding DGBinding = new Binding();
            DGBinding.Source = KB.VertexListe;
            DGBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            DG.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            DG.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, DGBinding);
            if (DG.ItemsSource == null) {
                DG.ItemsSource = KB.VertexListe;
                DG.Items.Refresh();
            } else {
                DG.ItemsSource = null;
                DG.ItemsSource = KB.VertexListe;
                DG.Items.Refresh();
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }

private void DG_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Koordinaten")
        {
            DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            templateColumn.Header = e.PropertyName;
            DataTemplate DT = new DataTemplate();
            templateColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["DGCellTemplate"];
            templateColumn.CellEditingTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["DGCellEditingTemplate"];
            templateColumn.SortMemberPath = "Koordinaten";
            e.Column = templateColumn;
        }
 }
```

I set the ItemsSource in code-behind because depending on the vertinsttria-variable different things are displayed in the datagrid.

Does anybody know how I can reach the aimed way of showing the data?

Greetings from Germany

Trainfan884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DataGrid inside a DataGrid is not the way to go, use an `ItemsControl` instead :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication15.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wpfApplication15="clr-namespace:WpfApplication15"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="618"
        Height="439"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources />
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding }"
                  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance wpfApplication15:MyObject}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Points">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication15
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            var objects = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>(new[]
            {
                new MyObject {Name = "Object1", Points = new float[] {1, 2}},
                new MyObject {Name = "Object2", Points = new float[] {3, 4}}
            });
            DataContext = objects;
        }
    }

    internal class MyObject
    {
        public Single[] Points { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

But now you have another problem : how to correctly present it using a mathematical notation ?

Some hints :

[library for visualizing mathematical equations (like an equation editor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012543/library-for-visualizing-mathematical-equations-like-an-equation-editor/5012907#5012907)

[How to render a formula in WPF or WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899204/how-to-render-a-formula-in-wpf-or-winforms)

Comment: thx, this solve the Problem, the brackets around the vector aren't that important to me.

Comment: Cool because from what I've been trying thus far it's not as straight forward as it should be :D